# Can I still use the table of Clebsh-Gordan coefficients if isospin isn't conserved, to calculate the branching ratio?

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, group-theory, isospin-symmetry

the title is basically everything. For example, the interaction $\Lambda^0 \rightarrow \Sigma^+ + \pi^-$ or $\Lambda^0 \rightarrow \Sigma^0 + \pi^0$. Isospin isn't conserved but the interaction is still possible, right?

Comment: wh... wh... *WHY* is isospin violated? The quark content remains the same. But this decay is prevented by the superior mass of the actual products. Please fix your question!

Comment: Isospin for $\lambda^0$ is 0 because it's a singlet. $\sigma^+$ and $\sigma^-$ have both Isospin 1. Or have I misunderstood something?
Yes, I overlooked that the quark content remains the same and corrected the question according to this.

Comment: Both the Σ *and* the  π have isospin 1. Two isotriplets easily combine to an isosinglet. What on earth are you talking about??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Λ has mass ~ 1.116 GeV, so below threshold for the
Σ(1.189) and π(0.140) system to decay to.

By contrast, the isosinglet Λ(1.405) is above that threshold and can and ***does*** decay to Σπ, strongly, 100% of the time. Isospin 1⊗1 of the products can, indeed, combine to an isosinglet, so  isospin 0 is conserved. You can, and *must* use the [C-G coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients#_j1_=_1,_j2_=_1) to compute the BRs. What do you find?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just start realizing that my Lecturer didn't teach me everything about Isospin. I learned that Isospin adds together by components so I thought that the Isospin would be violated. Do you have some sources you would recommend for a proper description of Isospin?

Comment: All introductory texts on particle physics cover the subject: Griffiths, Perkins, etc... isospin adds like angular momentum which it is modeled after: How do you add two spin 1s to make a spin 0?

Comment: $s = |s_1 - s_2|, ...,  |s_1 + s_2|$ so s = 0,1 is possible. For angular momentum, this isn't new to me. In the lecture, we had the example: the isospin of this state $(p,\pi^-)$ is $| 1/2, 1/2 \rangle + |1, -1\rangle = |3/2, -1/2 \rangle$. It's not mentioned that it could be something different. If I got it correctly what you said, $|1/2, -1/2 \rangle$, $|3/2, 1/2 \rangle$  and $|3/2, 3/2 \rangle$ would also be possible?

Comment: No; the spin adds as you wrote, but m, the third component, so, here, the eigenvalue of $I_3$, ads conventionally, numerically. So $|1/2,-1/2\rangle$ is allowable, but not the other two states!

Comment: Okay, thank you a lot!